# Why will Github API let me access but NOT list private repos?

Tags: python, git, api, github, oauth

I have written a small script to download all issues on GitHub repos from either my personal or organizational repos.  **The full code is itself on github [here]**(https://github.com/joereddington/Vision/blob/master/downloadissues.py)

I use a personal access token for authentication.

When I access a private repository (I have one called whitewaterwriters) directly like this:

```
issues = []    
issues.extend(get_json_from_url('https://api.github.com/repos/equalitytime/whitewaterwriters' + '/issues?state=all&filter=all'))
    issues = sorted(issues, key=lambda k: k['title'])
    for issue in issues:
        print issue['title']
        download_comment_to_file(issue['title'], issue['comments_url'])
```

It happily prints out all issues from the private repo.

However, when I use more general code:

```
repos = []
repos = get_json_from_url(MY_REPO_ROOT+'/repos')
repos.extend(get_json_from_url(EQT_REPO_ROOT+'/repos'))
issues = []
for repo in repos:
    if repo['has_issues']:
        issues.extend(get_json_from_url(repo['url'] + '/issues?state=all&filter=all'))
issues = sorted(issues, key=lambda k: k['title'])
for issue in issues:
    print issue['title']
    download_comment_to_file(issue['title'], issue['comments_url'])
```

...I get all of the content from my public repositories, but none of the private repositories are visible.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is  `MY_REPO_ROOT+'/repos'` a valid url ? what are you getting in`repos` var ?

Comment: Repos var is giving me well formed output containing all of the information aobut *public* repos. I've edited my question to make this a little clearer...

Comment: Did you ask on github support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just `GET /user/repos` ?

as mentioned here [list your repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories)

Looks like `GET /users/:username/repos` is to list only public repos :[list user public repos](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories)

Comment: Yes, the bit I hadn't understood was that /user/repos should be understood as "All the repos for the authenticated user" whereas the other can be used without authentication...